PostgreSQL 16 compatible with Oracle Linux 7.9?
I tried to install postgresql 16 in Oracle Linux 7.9 environment but its failed, due to no package available. but postgresql 15, 12 able to install in oracle linux 7.9 somehow. i have been searching over the website but i cant see any post regarding the compatible problem. Please guide.
To install postgresql 16 in oracle linux 7.9

No PostgreSQL package available, or one of its dependencies? Are you using the PostgreSQL Yum repository ?

Yes, im using the Yum repository. Just show no postgresql16-server available, Error nothing to do

You can see the yum repository here: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/16/redhat/ There are entries for rhel-7Server-x86_64, which is what Oracle 7 uses, but looks like they're dead symlinks. Ditto rhel-7.9-x86_64.

Isn't it time to upgrade that old Linux version? Oracle Linux 7 goes out of support this year. Oracle was paid to support the OS for 10 years but none of that money went to the maintainers of the open source software running on it, like PostgreSQL. And even Oracle support doesn't cover backporting new features. Not even fixes beyond "reasonable commercial efforts"

EOL RH 7 ...as of Aug 2023.

Any Linux is compatible with PostgreSQL v16 if the software installed satisfies the requirements for PostgreSQL v16.
PostgreSQL doesn't provide binary packages of new versions for old, outdated operating systems. You will have to build PostgreSQL from source.

If you install PostgreSQL v16.1 on a hypervisor (VMware), then according to VMware documentation. VMware Postgres is currently supported only on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) version 8, and RHEL version 9. This applies to the core database software and client components such as ODBC and JDBC. You can go through the following VMware documentation to study in detail:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Postgres/16.1/vmware-postgres/supported-platforms.html
